# Is there any way of fetching sensors data if watch app goes in background or de-activated?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I am working on watch app extension in which I am collecting the data from all sensors (Accelerometer, pedometer, gyroscope, barometer,  location, heart rate etc) in maximum of 100HZ frequency, but I am facing problem with sensors stop giving data in following scenarios:

1. If I drop my arm then sensor works for few seconds after that, sensors do not provide data until I raise my wrist again.
2. Any point of time code execution stops so that we do not get data.

So I used `CMSensorRecorder` class but only this class can not fulfil our requirement.

so what is the way to get sensor data independent of active/de-activate state of `WKInterfaceController`?
I have to fetch data if app is in foreground state, either active state or de-active state.

Answer (score 0):

Background execution is only allowed on watchOS for a period longer than 3minutes when your app is running a Workout. You cannot fetch any sensor data in the background unless your app is running a Workout.

However, as [the official App Programming Guide for watchOS states](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/iOSSupport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH21-SW10), you shouldn't be running any tasks in the background unless your app is a Workout app, so I'd suggest you to reconsider how your app works.

Comment: @user3350097 if you found my answer useful, please consider accepting it

Answer (score 0):

Enabling location background mode and setting [`CLLocationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620568-allowsbackgroundlocationupdates) will keep your app recording sensor data in the background.